# Recommendations for Moving data from Operational Oracle RDBMS to GCP BigQuery or Cloud Storage

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata, google-cloud-storage

I wonder whether some of you have recommendations based on experience of how to move daily data from a on-premise Oracle RDBMS to a GCP service such as BigQuery and Cloud Storage.

In my organization, we are looking for change data capture (CDC), orchestration, scheduling and triggering in order to design and develop a robust process in production. Afterwards, we should proceed to acquire ad-hoc licenses and tools. Since we are just starting in a huge subscription with GCP, we urge in defining these kind of connection component.

We are gauging to use Oracle GoldenGate, but it seems to be quite limited for a end-to-end process.

What may you suggest then? Thanks in advance for sharing your experience.

Alan.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple companies that handle moving data from various databases to BigQuery:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/

Others have published their in-house built methods:

- WePay syncs their MySQL to BigQuery

  - https://wecode.wepay.com/posts/bigquery-wepay
- How to sync MongoDB to BigQuery

  - https://towardsdatascience.com/using-mongodb-change-streams-to-replicate-data-into-bigquery-64ab54636b0e